# Replacing all whitespace between brackets using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace all unnecessary whitespace between brackets in lisp-like code like this:

```
(print (number->string (     (func? '+ '-) 12 13 14 15)   )  )
```

So that it becomes:

```
(display (number->string ((func? '+ '-) 12 13 14 15)))
```

I know it looks really simple at first sight, but it's really tricky(at least to me). Here's
what I've tried:

```
In [14]: re.sub(r"\)[ \t]*\)","))",")) ) ",0)
Out[14]: ')) ) '

In [15]: re.sub(r"\)[ \t]*\)","))",") ) ",0)
Out[15]: ')) '

In [16]: re.sub(r"\)[ \t]+\)","))",")) ) ",0)
Out[16]: '))) '

In [17]: re.sub(r"\)[ \t]+\)","))","))  ) ",0)
Out[17]: '))) '

In [18]: re.sub(r"\)[ \t]+\)","))",")   )  ) ",0)
Out[18]: '))  ) '

In [19]: re.sub(r"\)[ \t]+\)","))",")   )  ) ",1)
Out[19]: '))  ) '

In [20]: re.sub(r"\)[ \t]+\)","))",")   )  ) ",0)
Out[20]: '))  ) '

In [21]: re.sub(r"\)[ \t]+\)","))",")   )  ) ",0,re.M)
Out[21]: '))  ) '

In [22]: re.sub(r"\).+\)","))",")   )  ) ",0,re.M)
Out[22]: ')) '

In [23]: re.sub(r"\)\s+\)","))",")   )  ) ",0,re.M)
Out[23]: '))  ) '

In [24]: re.sub(r"\)([ \t]*)\)","))",") ) ",0)
Out[24]: ')) '

In [25]: re.sub(r"\)([ \t]*)\)","",") ) ",0)
Out[25]: ' '

In [26]: re.sub("\)([ \t]*)\)","))",") ) ",0)
Out[26]: ')) '

In [27]: re.sub("\)([ \t]*)\)","))",") ) )",0)
Out[27]: ')) )'

In [28]: re.sub("\)([ \t]*)\)","))",") )       )",0)
Out[28]: '))       )'

In [29]: re.sub("\)([ \t]*?)\)","))",") )       )",0)
Out[29]: '))       )'

In [30]: re.sub("\)(.+?)\)","))",") )       )",0)
Out[30]: '))       )'
```

In every case above, `re.sub` replaces the whitespace between the first brackets only and leaves the rest of the string the same way it was before. I need a regexp to replace all the whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first replacement already "eats up" two of the three closing parentheses; therefore the second pair (second and third) of closing parentheses are not matched. You'll notice that if you add a fourth closing parenthesis to your sample text, whitespace will be eliminated between the second pair.

You must either substitute in a loop (until no replacements are made) or use a *lookahead assertion*:

```
re.sub(r"\)[ \t]*(?=\))",")",") )    )",0)
```

What that's doing is *matching* `\)[ \t]*` but only "peeking" to check whether a `\)` *follows*—that's what's called a lookahead assertion. (There are *lookbehind assertions* as well, and also *negative* lookahead and lookbehind assertions.)